# How can I use a custom template with Fuse Angular Calendar?

Tags: angular, calendar, fuse

I'm using Fuse Angular Calendar and mwl-calendar-month-view. Having some trouble when using a custom template ([openDayEventsTemplate]). My real problem is when I call the calendar event to show which events I have in the specific clicked day, the calendar is already coming with the header that I'll show in the image.
The ng-template must be loaded just when I click on a specific day.

[image: calendar]